# How to limit transactions to only approve addresses?

Tags: go-ethereum, accounts, security

I am dealing with a private consortium scenario (private Ethereum network) where all participants are known in advance and have assigned an addresses used in genesis. Like to know if its possible to limit the any transaction on the network to these addresses? Another way of saying it is if its possible to whitelist the addresses?

From technical side using geth 1.7.3 and all members in the consortium have permission to mine blocks so have full visibility into all transactions. Its just I don't know at the moment how to ensure reject transactions which are not in the genesis file.